# PHP files not loading on ajax calls (AWS server)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, amazon-web-services

The following error is being thrown in the browser console while ajax calls are made in the AWS server

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://<awsdns>/folder/webpage.php. 
Origin http://awsdns is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Here is how ajax call is being made

```
    $.ajax({
        type    : 'POST',
        url     : gbWebroot+'folder/webpage.php',
        data    : postFormData,
        dataType: 'json',
        encode  : true,
        success     : function(data) {

        }
    });
```

Any idea why this error is being thrown?

Comment: Try to set `dataType` to `jsonp`. This article might help: http://hayageek.com/cross-domain-ajax-request-jquery/

Comment: adding jsonp resulted in another error. SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'. Parse error. This issue does not happen in test servers and only in Live

Comment: Also the link provided says this "This works in all the browsers but the problem is: JSONP supports only GET method. POST method is not allowed". The request above is POST

Comment: Yes, but the link also shows an alternative approach using `CORS`